# How to avoid JQuery globalEval call when using AngularJS in Chrome Packaged Apps?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-chrome-app, content-security-policy

I am building a Chrome Packaged App, where according to CSP I am not allowed to use eval() method. Now since I'm using JQuery (version 1.10.2) and AngularJS (version 1.0.6), one of the library method calls JQuery globalEval internally. (globalEval calls eval internally, which can not be used in this context)

Has anyone come across the same issue? Any workaround other than re-engineering JQuery/AngularJS library method?

Comment: I have been having a similar trouble.  When I tried to add AngularJs 1.2.0-rc.2 to my packaged app in a basic way, I got errors from lines 8789 and 7861 (of the non-minified version).  The errors were both: "Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback."  All the Google docs say AngularJs is OK, but apparently not.

Comment: Double check whether you have any inline javascript code. Although there are some internal eval calls in AngularJS library, but I've managed to work around it finally. I found I had some inline jquery code which was causing the problem somehow by calling some AngularJS methods which in turn calls Eval.

Answer (score 6):

Both angular and jquery works with CSP without any problems. But angular needs extra configuration for this :[ngCsp](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCsp)

In short, you will have to add `ng-csp` directive to the `<html>` tag. This will tell angular that CSP is enabled, and it will not try to do things forbidden by CSP.